# Good way to opensource a Web Application with git

Tags: git, github, version-control, workflow, open-source

I'm writing a web application in PHP and want to opensource it. Right now I have a private git repository, which I don't want to make public (with custom configurations, f.e. db login credentials).

What would be a clean way to opensource the web app? Have a special branch with dummy config files (then my config files would be available too?)? Or fork from the opensourced repository?

I want to track both (the opensourced and the configured repo) with git.

Best,JotPe

Comment: Hi there! Your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow since it is not a direct, programming related issue, but rather about licensing. You may be able to get an answer at [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com). Be sure to read their on-topic page too. :D

Answer (score 1):

> Right now I have a private git repository, which I don't want to make public (with custom configurations, f.e. db login credentials).

In general, configuration doesn't belong in your repository.

One common approach is to include a configuration "template" like `config.ini.template` that is tracked, but require users to copy that to `config.ini`, which is `.gitignore`d, and load configuration from there.

Another approach popularized by [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) is to [load your configuration from environment variables](http://12factor.net/config).

If you choose to go down either of these paths, you should know that simply removing your currently tracked files with `git rm --cached` will *not* purge them from your repository. Previous commits will still contain your database credentials.

You could use something like [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) or [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to purge them from your repository, but this will cause commits to be rewritten which can cause serious problems, especially on shared repositories. I don't recommend this option unless you fully understand and accept the implications.

My preferred approach would be to `git rm --cached` the files (or possibly `git mv config.ini config.ini.template`), add them to your `.gitignore`, and then change the credentials themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As mentioned on the 12-factor App Website it's a bad idea to include config into code, especially with several branches (develop, production, ...). Assuming I remove the configuration completely from my code, how could I keep track of the config (for my different environments (dev, prod, ...))?

Comment: @JotPe, it depends what you mean by "keep track of". Do you need it to be _versioned_? Your needs may be different from mine, but I rarely need to do that. Do you simply need to _document them_ somewhere? Your repository host might have a wiki that you could use for that. Or you could use a shared Google doc.